# How Does One Refresh the File List Using FuzzyFinder in Vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, fuzzyfinder

Using the FuzzyFinder plugin in Vim, how does one regenerate the file list displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 :ruby finder.rescan!
```

You can map that to something if you need to do it often.

Comment: You can map to F12 key with:

 :map <special> <F12> :ruby finder.rescan!<ENTER>

Comment: When I try this, I get "NameError: undefined local variable or method `finder' for main:Object".

Answer (score 22):

Fuzzy Finder has a command called :FufRenewCache

Earlier versions of Fuzzy Finder had something similar, but I can't remember the command now.

Just try typing

:Fuf
or
:FuzzyFinder

And see what possible commands are shown in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable caching by putting following settings in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:fuf_help_cache_dir = ''
let g:fuf_tag_cache_dir = ''
let g:fuf_taggedfile_cache_dir = ''
```